# Sapui5 column of links

Tags: sapui5

I have a column of links. I want each link to display different information in a popup box when clicked. How can I accomplish this?

Here is the column I have created:

```
oControl = new sap.m.Link({ text: "{userEmails}" });
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column("userEmails", {
    label: new sap.m.Label({ text: "User Emails" }),
    template: oControl,
    sortProperty: "userEmails",
    filterProperty: "userEmails"
}));
```

I want the users emails to be displayed based on what row the link was clicked.

EDIT: Here's what I tried:

```
onLinkPressed: function (oEvent) {
    var obj = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getObject();
    var email = obj.email;
}
```

email is another column.
When I click the link nothing happens.

EDIT2: I have also tried this:

```
oControl = new sap.m.Link({text: "{userEmails}", press: function() {openDialog();}});         // edited from the first line of code I posted

function openDialog() {
    var oDialog1 = new sap.ui.commons.Dialog();
    oDialog1.setTitle("My first Dialog");
    var oText = new sap.ui.commons.TextView({ text: "example@email.com" });
    oDialog1.addContent(oText);
    oDialog1.addButton(new sap.ui.commons.Button({ text: "OK", press: function () { oDialog1.close(); } }));
    oDialog1.open();
}
```

This creates an open dialog but each link gives the same information and I want each link to give different information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! Here's my working code:

```
oControl = new sap.m.Link({ text: "{userEmails}", press: function (oEvent) { openDialog(oEvent);}});
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column("userEmails", {
    label: new sap.m.Label({ text: "User Emails" }),
    template: oControl,
    sortProperty: "userEmails",
    filterProperty: "userEmails",

}));

function openDialog(oEvent) {
    var oDialog1 = new sap.ui.commons.Dialog();
    oDialog1.setTitle("Emails");
    var obj = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getObject();
    var email = obj.email;
    var oText = new sap.ui.commons.TextView({ text: email });
    oDialog1.addContent(oText);
    oDialog1.addButton(new sap.ui.commons.Button({ text: "OK", press: function () { oDialog1.close(); } }));
    oDialog1.open();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general you can attach an event handler for **press** event to the link and open a popup in the in the event handler. The text of the link can be obtained as follows:

```
onLinkPressed : function(event) {
    var link = event.getSource();
    var email = link.getText();
}
```