# How to create links on the column of table in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Could anyone please give me some idea how to create links on table column contents (only for two columns) and this contents are coming from **ODATA** service and after pressing any content it should go to the particular link?

Ex. Suppose the every table content has {mainUrl} and

For 1st column:
Deep Link: /bb/ccc/eee?reqid = 
Example URL: {mainUrl}/bb/ccc/eee?reqid=6000

For 2nd column:
Deep Link: /bb/cc/fff?jobid=
Example: {mainUrl}/bb/cc/fff?jobid=4000

I tried couple of the examples: [ex-1](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.m.Link), [ex-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579554/sapui5-column-of-links). But I'm not sure how to fix it for this case. I'd really appreciate if you could provide me some example codes if it's possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example how to create links on table columns is based on [Link - Subtle](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Link/sample/sap.m.sample.LinkSubtle) example.

1. In the /mockdata/products.json for each 'ProductPicUrl' field value remove a host name `'https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com'`.
2. As a result the link in the column has got a **host** of the dev server, eg is `'http://localhost:8081/test-resources/sap/ui/documentation/sdk/images/HT-2001.jpg'`
3. In the Link.view.xml view change the first column content by adding
   a formatter function see [Walkthrough Step 22: Custom Formatters](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de):

   ```
   <ColumnListItem>
     <Link
       text="{Name}"
       href="{
         path: 'ProductPicUrl',
         formatter: '.hrefFormatter'
       }" />
   ```
4. And implement the formatter in the Link.view.xml controller file:

   ```
   hrefFormatter: function(sUrl) {
       var mainUrl = 'https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com';
       return mainUrl + sUrl;
   }
   ```
5. Using the formatter provides modified link URL: `'https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/documentation/sdk/images/HT-1002.jpg'`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by writing the codes in JS file:

```
createAllColumns: function () {
.....
.....
 var oTemplate = new Text({
                        text: sText,
                        wrapping: false
                    }); // for default columns

                    if (oChar.charId === "columnID") {
                        oTemplate = new Link({
                            text: sText,
                            press: this.readTheID
                        });
                    }
......
......
},

readTheID: function (oEvent) {
            const oBind = oEvent.getSource().getParent().getBindingContext("service name");
            const obj = oBind.getObject().columnID;
            const value = oEvent.getSource().getProperty("text");

            return models.getInstance().getOdataWrapper().getEntitySet({
                path: "/OdataServiceEntitySet",
                filters: [new Filter({ path: "name", operator: FilterOperator.EQ, value1: "mainUrl" }),
                new Filter({ path: "columnID", operator: FilterOperator.EQ, value1: obj })],
                And: true
            }).then((odata) => {
                if (odata.length > 0) {
                    var mainLink = odata[0].getObject().value;
                    sap.ui.require([
                        "sap/m/library"
                    ], sapMLib => sapMLib.URLHelper.redirect(mainLink + "/bb/ccc/eee?reqid=" + value, /*new window*/true));
                }
            }).catch((err) => {
                sap.m.MessageToast.show("Failed");
            });

        },
```

**Note**: "sap/m/Link" produces dynamic links. In that case we can't reserve the links into the column contents, that's why user can't copy the link directly from the content.